# Copying DB's over in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am going to be doing some major DB restructuring in MongoDB that converts a bunch of records.  I've ran this script against a copied DB locally and it works fine, so it *should* also work on the production database.

Is there an easy way of copying a DB instance into a new DB?  I figured I could shut down MongoDB and copy the files into a new directory, rename them to the new DB, and then move them into the MongoDB data directory.

It's usually pretty slow to copy large DB files like that, so I wondered if there was a Mongo-specific way of copying DB's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it is sufficient to copy only some collections, you can copy them as follows without shutting down the db server:

http://xmlquerying.blogspot.de/2012/10/copying-data-between-mongo-databases.html

Otherwise use mongodump and mongorestore.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/